# Как удалить повторяющиеся слова в строке php?

Tags: php

Как можно удалить повторяющиеся слова в строке на этом примере

```
while ($arr = $res->fetch_array()){

  $q = explode(", ", substr(','.$arr['text'].',', 1, -1));
  $count = count($q);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

      echo $q[$i].'</br>'; // Нужно убрать повтор слов

    }

}

Выводит слова:

Текст1
Текст1
Текст
Тест

Слово Текст1 должно выводится только одно, без повторов
```

Пробовал вот так

```
function del($text){
    $text = implode(array_reverse(preg_split('//u', $text)));
    $text = preg_replace('/(\b[\pL0-9]++\b)(?=.*?\1)/siu', '', $text);
    $text = implode(array_reverse(preg_split('//u', $text)));
    return $text;
}

$hello = 'привет, привет, тест';

echo del($hello);
```

Убирает повторения, но на моем примере не работает

```
echo del($q[$i]).'</br>';
```

Comment: это вы про array_unique() спрашиваете?

Comment: Не знаю даже, гуглил пробовал несколько вариантов, но в for {} на этом примере почему то не работают

Comment: причем тут for, посмотрите, как функция работает

Comment: Та смотрел же пробовал какие то варианты(, не хочет(

Comment: так покажите ваш код с пробами, образцом входных данных и результатом

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил код как пробовал

Comment: как мы поймем, почему не работает?  надо смотреть входные данные. приведите пример с такими параметрами, когда не работает

Comment: Понял, добавил пример как выводит сейчас

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/693e5

Comment: Можно также здесь сделать? https://onlinephp.io/c/b08d9

Comment: вы я так понимаю, даже не смотрели, что делает код, который я вам показал. Здесь правят ошибки в коде, а не пишут его для других. Попробуйте сами

Comment: Смотрел и пробовал по вашему примеру, также как и с другими примерами, пробовал с моим примером не хочет работать(